# Decoding and resizing image is giving unknown tensor shape

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I'm trying to load two images, *one is **.png** and another is **.jpg**,* to *tensorflow* and resize them to 100x100 pixel size using `tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box`, so that they will be of same size and can be used for training. Here's my code:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf

def decode(image_data):
    return tf.image.decode_image(image_data, channels=3)

def adjust_paddig(image_tensor):
    return tf.image.pad_to_bounding_box(image_tensor, offset_height=0, offset_width=0, target_height=100, target_width=100)

def load(images_paths):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(images_paths)
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    _, image_file = reader.read(filename_queue)
    image_tensor = decode(image_file)
    padded_image_tensor = adjust_paddig(image_tensor)
    return padded_image_tensor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IMAGES_PATH = ["images/1.png","images/2.jpg"] # Both image are of different shape
    class_images_tensor = load(IMAGES_PATH)
    print(class_images_tensor.shape)
```

But some how the resized image size is not proper. It's displaying height and width but not depth(I mean channels).

```
Output: (100,100,?) #height, width are 100, but depth is '?'
```

and Surprisingly, It's giving same output for invalid paths also.

```
Eg: IMAGES_PATH = ['images/']
```

What Am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, decode_image does not give a fully defined tensor shape because it supports gif as well - which seems a bit like scope creep.
Also, decode_jpeg silently handles PNG just fine now, and has a fully defined tensor shape.

Comment: Wow I just had the same issue and that's totally not what I expected. Talk about tensorflow being unintuitive. Is there any way to use decode_image, but add the shapes manually?